# JQuery On change, keyup not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with a really simple function that is trying to fire when a text box changes.  This seems to be a commonly asked question, but most of the time seems to revolve around the top $(document).ready being missing.

however this is stumping me.  I  have a number of other JQuery elements firing correctly, but this one doesn't seem to want to.  Any ideas guys?

```html
detection: <input type="text" placeholder="detect value" name="txt_detection" id="txt_detection">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt_detection').on('change, keyup', function(){
    alert "oops!";
  });
});
```

I have it in a fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/hzmjjzd9/

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. Firstly `on()` accepts each event in a single string that's *space* delimited, not comma delimited. Secondly, you're missing the brackets when you call `alert()`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt_detection').on('change keyup', function() {
    alert("oops!");
  });
});
```

Alternatively you can use the `input` event as it convers additional methods of amending the content of an input element, such as pasting using the mouse.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#txt_detection').on('input', function() {
    console.log("oops!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
detection:
<input type="text" placeholder="detect value" name="txt_detection" id="txt_detection">
```

Comment: Also he didn't include the jquery library in his jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

What if your both concerns solves by single change event as follows,
Your jsfiddle doesnt have jquery library and your alert syntax was wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt_detection').on('input', function() {
    alert("oops!");
  });
});
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzmjjzd9/3/).

Give it a try, this should work.

[Document-ready Document](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Thanks  guys this is really useful.  Cant add to reputation yes as mine is too low.

Comment: You can, try it out ;)